# Вывод изображения на форму

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Начал изучать VK_API и пытаюсь написать окно которое будет выводить список друзей с аватаркой, написал такой код:

```
rootFriends = Tk()  # Создание окна
rootFriends.title("Друзья")
rootFriends.geometry("400x800")
rootFriends.configure(background='black')
scrollbar = Scrollbar(rootFriends)  # Создание скроллбара
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
mylist = Listbox(rootFriends, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set,width=400,background="black", foreground="#ccc",height=20)  # Создание листбокса
idUser = vk.users.get(v=5.100)  # Получаю ID пользователя
friends = vk.friends.get(user_id=idUser[0]["id"], count="8",fields="city,domain,photo")  # Получаю список друзей
friends = friends["items"]
i = 0
while (i < len(friends)):
    resource = urllib.request.urlopen(friends[i]["photo"])  # Загружаю фото
    im=PIL.Image.open(resource)
    photo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    mylist.insert(END,friends[i]["first_name"]+" "+friends[i]["last_name"])  # Вывожу имена
    i += 1
mylist.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
scrollbar.config(command=mylist.yview)
rootFriends.mainloop()
```

Как сделать что бы в этом же `Listbox` было и изображение, или может какой другой объект использовать, то какой?

Comment: Listbox не поддерживает вывод изображений (или добавление элементов управления на него). Можно использовать Canvas вместо Listbox.